# Suppressing sign-extension when upcasting or shifting in Java

Tags: java

I have a feeling this is a rather trivial question, but I'm stumped. In my application I'm keying things in a lookup table with a pair of ints. I thought it would be easier to concatenate the two ints into one long and use the single long as a key instead. Coming from a C background, I was hoping something like this would work:

```
int a, b;
long l = (long)a << 32 | b;
```

My attempts to replicate this in Java have frustrated me. In particular, because there are no unsigned integral types, I can't seem to avoid the automatic sign-extension of b (a gets left-shifted so its irrelevant). I've tried using `b & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF` but it surprisingly has no  effect. I also tried the rather ugly `(long)b << 32 >> 32`, but it seemed to be optimized out by the compiler.

I was hoping to do this strictly using bit manipulation with primitives, but I'm starting to wonder if I need to use some sort of buffer object to achieve this.

Comment: `(long)b << 32 >> 32` is not optimized out. The main problem is that >> is sra and >>> is srl, which is what you want: `(long)b << 32 >>> 32`

Comment: The expression `b & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF` simply must work, but why do you obfuscate it by those zeros?

Comment: @maaartinus: I am not familiar enough with Java to know what it internally stores that hex literal as. I know in C hex literals are unsigned, but I was concerned that 0xFFFFFFFF would be sign extended. In hindsight, I only needed one leading zero to satisfy that concern. Still the expression is having no effect.

Comment: For sure, `0xFFFFFFFF` doesn't get sign-extended. But there's another problem, it's only an `int` (we both forgot the `L` suffix) and get promoted into a `long` - by sign extension, of course. That's why it can't work. The leading zeros change nothing, the literal is only an int. Look at my answer, it's surely right, I used it many times.

Comment: What you did is just like `(signed int) (b & 0xFFFFFFFF)` in C. The result is a signed int, and gets promoted to long by sign extension.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that the literal would be saved as an int. That explains why the mask was having no effect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I always use my utility class with

```
public static long compose(int hi, int lo) {
    return (((long) hi << 32) + unsigned(lo));
}
public static long unsigned(int x) {
    return x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
}

public static int high(long x) {
    return (int) (x>>32);
}
public static int low(long x) {
    return (int) x;
}
```

For any `int x, y` (negative or not)

```
high(compose(x, y)) == x
low(compose(x, y)) == y
```

holds and for any `long z`

```
compose(high(z), low(z)) == z
```

holds, too.

Comment: Would upvote you more than once if I could, sign extension was driving met nuts.

Comment: Shouldn't `high` use `>>>` rather than `>>`?

Comment: @JamesKo The values after the shift differ in their upper 32 bits only, i.e., in those cut away by the cast. You may want to use unsigned shift to demonstrate that you're not dealing with signedness, but I chose to use signed shift to demonstrate that it doesn't matter. ;)

Comment: As of Java 1.8, there's now `Integer.toUnsignedLong` to do this conversion

Answer (score 1):

I do this from time to time - I store two ints in a long for my X Y coordinates. Because I know my range will never be more than 1 billion, I do the following:

```
private Long keyFor(int x, int y) {
    int kx = x + 1000000000;
    int ky = y + 1000000000;
    return (long)kx | (long)ky << 32;
}

private Long keyFor(int[] c) {
    return keyFor(c[0],c[1]);
}

private int[] coordsFor(long k) {
    int x = (int)(k & 0xFFFFFFFF) - 1000000000;
    int y = (int)((k >>> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF) - 1000000000;
    return new int[] { x,y };
}
```

Comment: This is no general solution and makes the composition hard to decipher. Composing numbers in the normal way works, is much faster, and allows to see the components directly in the hex output.

Comment: "Composing numbers in the normal way" didn't work - I wouldn't have taken this route if it did. It is the exact issue OP is running in to. And it is not all that difficult to follow. I certainly don't see it as downvote criteria, since this is a potential solution, even if you feel it is more obfuscated than necessary.

Comment: I don't like it since it introduces *unnecessary* obfuscation. Doing it "the normal way" works, assuming you prevent sign extension as I did. Then you need no constant to add not you need to assume *anything* about the numbers involved.

Comment: By not providing the constant, you limit yourself to only positive numbers. So you are actually making assumptions about your numbers, whether you like it or not.

Comment: I do NOT limit myself to positive numbers! See my edited answer, try to find a counterexample.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll concede the functionality aspect. I maintain that while mine is contains unnecessary logic, I it is not unnecessarily obfuscated. The logic inside it no more difficult to decipher than yours, as the curve of understanding is set at reading bit shifts. The additions are straightforward enough. In the project this is in, I actually abandoned it in favor of `class Coordinate { private int x; private int y; // etc }`