# Convert Hexadecimal String #b2c2d6 into Int like 0x2c2d6

Tags: java, hex

im currently working at a new Feature where i need to extract the main color of an image. I got an int array after extracting with the three rgb colors of the dominant color of that image. After that im converting those rgb colors into a string

`String hexString = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", dominantColor[0], dominantColor[1], dominantColor[2]);`

this returns like `#b2c2d6`. Now i want to convert this string into an integer, which is holding my hexadecimal value like

`int hexInt = 0xb2c2d6`

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Yes there is, and there is also a more direct way to take `dominantColor[0]` and the other two and concatenate them into an `int` without going through a string, are you also interested in the latter?

Comment: Yeah sure, how can i accomplish that?

Comment: Like this: [convert 3 bytes to int in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13154715/555045)

Comment: After doing it like this, i get an integer like ```443058``` but i need it to be like ```0xb2c2d6```

Comment: OK, put the bytes in the opposite order

Comment: Just to make sure, am i converting them right? ```byte b1 = (byte)dominantColor[0] byte b2 = (byte)dominantColor[1]; byte b3 = (byte)dominantColor[2]; int r = (b3 & 0xFF) | ((b2 & 0xFF) << 8) | ((b1 & 0x0F) << 16);```

Comment: Oh I see, there was a quirk in that other question that removed 4 bits, but you do have those bits, so 0x0F should be 0xFF here. Other than that it looks fine. The casts to byte are not really necessary.

Comment: Still not getting an Integer like i need it. Im getting now ```int r = 14074546```

Comment: Right yes it's still reversed, switch the bytes around, `b1 = (byte)dominantColor[2]` etc

Comment: Still not getting the needed result, im still getting ```r=12759766```

Comment: The second and third byte are still the wrong way around, also please stop showing the result in decimal, I have a hard time figuring out what the result means and what's wrong with it. BTW in case it's not clear, the right result is 11715286, which is equal to 0xb2c2d6.

Comment: Possible to store them like 0xFFFFFF instead of decimal?

Comment: Integers are not decimal or hexadecimal. That's just the way you *print* the number. The number `11715286` for example is exactly the same number as `0xb2c2d6`, just printed in decimal instead of hexadecimal.